# Как правильно объединить 2 JS?

Tags: javascript

Есть скрипт, переключения Языка страницы

```
var htmlElement = document.querySelector("html");

document.querySelector("label").onclick = function() {
  if(htmlElement.getAttribute("lang") == "en") {
    document.querySelector("html").setAttribute("lang", "ru");
  } else if(htmlElement.getAttribute("lang") == "ru") {
    document.querySelector("html").setAttribute("lang", "en");
  }
}
```

Он привязан к CSS
таким образом

```
:root:lang(en) {
  --home: "Tickets";
  --Notification: "Notification";
   --sale: "Airline offers";
     --schedule: "Flight schedule";
     --search: "Find cheap flights";
     --buy: "Hurry up to buy cheap";
     --language-selection-phrase: "En";
    --change-lang: "Ru";

:root:lang(ru){
    --home: "Авиабилеты";
    --sale: "Предложения авиакомпаний";
   --Notification: "Следить за ценой";
   --schedule: "Расписание авиарейсов";
   --search: "Поиск дешевых авиабилетов";
   --buy: "Успейте купить дёшево";
   --language-selection-phrase: "Ру";
  --change-lang: "En";
  
}
```

Создает две кнопки переключения языка на сайте. Так же на сайте есть некая форма, которая вызывается дивом и 2-мя скриптами, с кнопками переключения языка не связанная.

```
<div id="twidget" class="twidget-container"> </div>
```

и JS
Это вызов формы на русском языке

```
$('#twidget').twidget({
locale: 'ru',
default_origin: '',
type: 'avia',
});
```

Это вызов формы на английском

```
$('#twidget').twidget({
locale: 'en',
default_origin: '',
type: 'avia',
});
```

Мне необходимо скрипт переключения языков связать со скриптами вызова определенной формы.
То-бишь если кликаешь на RU, то и форма грузится эта

```
$('#twidget').twidget({
    locale: 'ru',
    default_origin: '',
    type: 'avia',
    });
```

и так же если кликаешь на en то уже выполняется английская форма.
Как это сделать, без перезагрузки страницы это реально?

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#twidget').twidget({
  locale: document.querySelector("html").getAttribute("lang"),
  default_origin: '',
  type: 'avia',
});
```

Comment: После загрузки страницы locale: document.querySelector("html").getAttribute("lang"),  остается не изменным и не меняется на ru Или en. То-бишь эта строчку не преобразуется в ru или en

Comment: @Arcadiy Я ничего не понял.